# choose filter in convolution neural network

Tags: conv-neural-network

I have done implementation part of convolution neural network. But I am still confused about how to select the filter to obtain convolved feature in convolution neural network. As I know we detect features(like eyes, nose, mouth) to recognize a face from an image using convolution layer with the help of the filter.is it true that filter contains eyes, nose, mouth to recognize a face from an image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to choose the number of filters in each Convolutional Layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328205/how-to-choose-the-number-of-filters-in-each-convolutional-layer)

Comment: I modified my question. It may be more clear to you guys.please reply

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard rule for this purpose.
In many university courses and even implemented models in papers, researcher uses 3x3 or 5x5 filters with with 1 or 2 strides.
It is one of your hyperparameters you should tune for your model. But the best way as a practice is to go to implemented model's documentations by google or others and find best size with respect to your conv layers.
But the last thing you should know is that the purpose of adding filters is to reduce nmber of parameters but keeping high quality features.
Here is a [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) to all models implemented using Tensoflow for different tasks.
Good luck

Comment: I modified my question. Can you explain again .is there any change in the answer?